# How can I activate conda venv in Dockerfile? (pip not found)

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile, miniconda

I'm trying to build a docker image like

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && \
        apt install -y git wget libsuitesparse-dev gcc g++ swig && \
        cd ~ && wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
        sh Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b && rm Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
        PATH=$PATH:~/miniconda3/condabin && \
        conda init bash && conda upgrade -y conda && /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc" && \
        pip install numpy scipy matplotlib scikit_umfpack
```

However, `/bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"` does not work... so I got `/bin/sh: 1: pip: not found`
How can I build a docker image installing miniconda and python requirements using pip at the same time?

Comment: The code `/bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc"` is meaningless — environment changes by `~/.bashrc` are immediately rolled back when the `bash` exits. `~/.bashrc` must be sourced into the **current** shell.

Comment: Can I recommend https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-virtualenv-dockerfile/ ?

Comment: Why are you running everything in your Dockerfile in a single RUN command?  You are losing almost all of the benefit of Docker's layered filesystem and layer caching.  As it seems that you are debugging just the last portions of all of the commands you're running, you'd be able to iterate much more quickly if you broke your commands into multiple RUN commands.  It would make your Dockerfile easier to read and understand.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I thought `ubuntu:latest` does not have `pip` by default.

Comment: @CryptoFool I've heard that every `RUN` command generates a temporary image at a time. So it makes the size of the final image get bigger.

Comment: @MinsikSeo - that's true mostly if you're changing data rather than adding new data.  If you're installing a new package, for example, then it's going to make the image bigger by the number of new bytes installed regardless of if that goes into one layer or two. If you're spending much time waiting for your images to built, then try giving multiple RUN commands a try. If you're like most of us, you won't be able to go back to doing all that waiting.  If you must, you can always put all of your commands into one RUN command once you've perfected the definition of your image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a pre-existing Docker image that already has Anaconda installed. For example, [this link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/docker/) has a Docker image endorsed by Anaconda itself. There may be others on Dockerhub that also have Anaconda installed already. In the case you already tried an image with  Anaconda and it didn't meet your needs, let me know.